# android spinner text size with layout.xml is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, spinner, android-spinner

I have this layout

```
spinnertipocombustible.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50dip"
        android:textColor="#ccddaa"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in dialogfragment I have this code

```
listado=DM.RegresaTiposCombustible();
adapter= new TiposCombustibleAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.spinnertipocombustible,listado);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinnertipocombustible);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in next picture you can see the text size which not change if I change
this line in spinnertipocombustible.xml

```
android:textSize="50dip"
```

[image]

this is my adapter..

```
public class TiposCombustibleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TipoCombustible>{

    private Context context;

    private List<TipoCombustible> tipoCombustibles;

    public TiposCombustibleAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<TipoCombustible> tiposCombustible){

        super(context,textViewResourceId,tiposCombustible);
        this.context=context;
        this.tipoCombustibles=tiposCombustible;

    }

    public  int getCount(){

        return  tipoCombustibles.size();
    }

    public TipoCombustible getItem(int position){
        return  tipoCombustibles.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position){
        return  position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // I created a dynamic TextView here, but you can reference your own  custom layout for each spinner item
        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        // Then you can get the current item using the values array (Users array) and the current position
        // You can NOW reference each method you has created in your bean object (User class)
        label.setText(tipoCombustibles.get(position).getDescripcion());

        // And finally return your dynamic (or custom) view for each spinner item
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        label.setText(tipoCombustibles.get(position).getDescripcion());

        return label;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `50sp` or `50dp` instead of `50dip`. You might also want to try to change `layout_height` to `wrap_content` instead of a fixed value.

Comment: i have change it to 500sp and size not changes

Comment: I have added my adapter maybe there is the error but I dont see it

Comment: doing this in adapter-> getview the size change         label.setTextSize(20);

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textSize). Available units for *android:textSize* are:

> Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp
>   (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches), mm
>   (millimeters).

So, instead of *android:textSize="50dip"*, use any acceptable unit (e.g., dp or sp).

Comment: i have change 50dip 50 sp and after 500 sp and text size not change

Comment: I have added my adapter maybe there is the error but I dont see it

Comment: doing this in adapter-> getview the size change         label.setTextSize(20);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android:textSize="50dip"`, use any acceptable unit like `dp` and `sp`.

Example

```
android:textSize="50dp"
android:textSize="50sp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use LinearLayout. just remove that layout
and increase your textsize. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

try  this code......
Remove linearlayout from your textview and use it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:textColor="#ccddaa"
    />
```